# How can I run mediainfo with specify folder?

Tags: python

this is my codes:

```
#!/usr/bin/python3
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

import os
import subprocess

dirr="/home/pi/hrc2/Film-Dizi/duzenle/The Handmaiden (2016)"
file="The.Handmaiden.2016.m1080p.BluRay.x264-DUAL.TR.KOR.mkv"

os.chdir(dirr)

sonuc=subprocess.check_output(['mediainfo','--Inform=General;%FileName%',file])
print(sonuc)
```

Error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):


File "/home/pi/hrc2/Film-Dizi/duzenle/dene.py", line 25, in <module>
    sonuc=subprocess.check_output(['mediainfo','--Inform=General;%FileName%',file])
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/subprocess.py", line 316, in check_output
    **kwargs).stdout
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/subprocess.py", line 398, in run
    output=stdout, stderr=stderr)
subprocess.CalledProcessError: Command '['mediainfo', '--Inform=General;%FileName%', 'The.Handmaiden.2016.m1080p.BluRay.x264-DUAL.TR.KOR.mkv']' returned non-zero exit status 1
```

Comment: Your ```print(sonuc)``` will never run. Wrap a ```try:``` & ```except:``` block round the ```subprocess ...``` call and print the return value in the ```except:``` handler.  https://stackoverflow.com/q/33239308/3491475

Comment: print(sonuc) works when the movie and python file are in the same folder but not in the different folder.

Comment: When things fail the print command will tell you what's gone wrong. Hence why I suggested running in a ```try:``` & ```except:``` block.